# Converting blob to image in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, image, blob

I'm storing images as blob in MySQL database,
I want to show the profile image to the user,
I'm using this sample code:
the `url` logged in the console shows an empty image
const authHeader = useAuthHeader();

```
const config = {
  headers: { authorization: `${authHeader()}` },
  responseType: "buffer",
};
const bodyParameters = {
  key: "value",
};
axios
  .get("http://localhost:3030/getImage", config, bodyParameters)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    const contentType = response.headers["content-type"];
    const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: contentType });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log("Image url;", url);
    setImageSrc(url);
  });
axios.post("http://localhost:4000/profile", bodyParameters, config);


 }, []);
     return (
        <div className="flex-col">
          Welcome to profile!!
          <img src={imageSrc} alt="image"></img>
        </div>
      );
```

EDIT:
Using postman the image is generated in json format:

```
{
    
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            123,
            34,
            110,
            97,
            109,
            101,
            34,
            58,
            34,
            55,
            48,
            51,
            48,
            55,
            51,
            48..]}
```

Comment: One of the problems is: using a regular number array with Blob, like `new Blob([1,2,3], ...)`, it will be treated as if it were `new Blob(['1','2','3'], ...)`, so the Uint8Array data becomes 49, 50, 51 rather than 1, 2, 3

Comment: here's newer version after converting to uint8array, still the same problem, I tried tweaking the content type also :
(``` console.log(response.data);
        const contentType = response.headers["content-type"];
        console.log("content type",contentType);
        const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(response.data);
        const blob = new Blob([uint8Array], { type: contentType });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log("Image url;", url);
        setImageSrc(url);```)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you keep `responseType: "buffer"`, you need to use `JSON.parse` it before you can further use the `.data` property within the json.
(If you changed it to `responseType: "buffer"`, then you don't need to parse it again, and the array of numbers is contained within `response.data.data`)

And since your response is json, but your blob needs an image type, the `response.headers["content-type"]` is not the right type. You need to get the type from elsewhere.

And after that, you also need to use some conversion involving Uint8Array before the Blob can contain the correct data.

```
    axios
        .get("http://localhost:3030/getImage", config, bodyParameters)
        .then((response) => {
            let jsObj = JSON.parse(response.data);
            const contentType = 'image/png'; //or some other type
            const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(jsObj.data);
            const blob = new Blob([uint8Array], { type: contentType });
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            setImageSrc(url);
        });
```

Comment: The image is guaranteed to be png ,`jsObj.data` is the array of integers retrieved from the image, the `url` is generated but contains nothing..

Comment: @Yahia It works properly with the image I tested, though. What do you have in `getImage`?

Comment: For testing purposes: json generated from a PNG image consisting of four blue pixels: `{"type":"Buffer","data":[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,8,6,0,0,0,114,182,13,36,0,0,0,1,115,82,71,66,0,174,206,28,233,0,0,0,4,103,65,77,65,0,0,177,143,11,252,97,5,0,0,0,9,112,72,89,115,0,0,14,194,0,0,14,194,1,21,40,74,128,0,0,0,22,73,68,65,84,24,87,99,100,88,244,226,63,3,16,48,129,8,6,6,6,6,0,37,224,2,141,76,214,145,3,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,68,174,66,96,130]}`. Here, `console.log(blob.size)` should give 129 if the blob is correct.

Comment: 1- Verifying the JWT token
2-Verify the email of the user logged in
3-return the picture related to the user's mail
something like this :
`const [rows2, fields2] = await db`
   ` .promise()`
 `   .execute("select * from photos where id = ?", [photo_id]);`
  
  `return res.json(rows2[0].data)`;

Comment: the data shown in the console is correct,an integer array with size of 92340 ,the retrievement from the backend is correct, it's just the conversion that's not properly done..

Comment: @Yahia: I found that your integer array contains more than just an image. The first integers
`[123,34,110,97,109,101,34,58,34,55,48,51,48,55,51,48]` represents `{"name":"7030730'`, not a png image. The first part of the png image should be more like the following: \x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252592/discussion-between-yahia-and-qrsngky).